# How to write an XPath for dynamic id?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

How can I write an XPath for an element with an `id` attribute that keeps changing?

HTML snippet:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number or Name" id="CCTFTW" name="CCTFTW" 
       onfocus="javascript:show('contacts');" class="ui-autocomplete-input" 
       autocomplete="off">
```

The `id` is `CCTFTW` this time but changes dynamically.

Comment: Are you trying to select the `id` attribute value, or are trying to select the `input` element and having trouble because the `id` is unstable?  What is stable -- `name` or `placeholder` attributes?  Something else about the context of the `input` element?

Comment: the values of id and name always changes and all other things remains stable/same. one more thing, the value of id(CCTFTW ) is always same as name as seen in the example.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath will select the `input` element whose `placeholder` attribute is `Enter Mobile Number or Name`, regardless of the current value of its `id`:

```
//input[@placeholder = 'Enter Mobile Number or Name']
```

If you need the `id` attribute of that `input` element:

```
//input[@placeholder = 'Enter Mobile Number or Name']/@id
```

Answer (score 0):

**If I resume:**

- you have a tag you want to find (and get inside data);
- with interesting index inside, but always changing: so it is not really an index for you;
- with other attributes, stable, but meaningless, and rather made for UI.

Conclusion: you cant rely on anything.

**Solution:**

- If you cant control the production of this xml (html ?), you wont be able to trust. You can try to select with placeholder, but not sure:

like that:

```
//input[@placeholder='Enter Mobile Number or Name']
```

- If you have a control over it:

1 put another very stable parameter inside: like

```
<input type="text" my_field="mobile_zone"
```

2 And get it with xpath

//input[@my_field='mobile_zone']